# Grouping Imports at Java

Tags: java, import

Does Java support grouping the imports like following:

```java
import package.{Class1,Class2}
```

I know that `*` operator imports sub packages but I want to import specific ones.

---

In `Rust` or some modern languages it is supported like following:

```rust
use package::{Class1, Class2};
```

***Are there any alternative instead of writing each import line by line specifically like this?***

```java
import package.Class1;
import package.Class2;
```

Comment: impressive  question

Comment: Seems that do not support?

Comment: For question like that, you should check the [**Java Language Specification**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java Language Specification, section [7.5. Import Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5), shows:

> An *import declaration* allows a named type or a `static` member to be referred to by a simple name ([§6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.2)) that consists of a single identifier.
>
> [...]
>
> - A single-type-import declaration ([§7.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1)) imports a **single named type**, by mentioning its canonical name ([§6.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7)).
> - A type-import-on-demand declaration ([§7.5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2)) imports **all the accessible types** of a named type or named package as needed, by mentioning the canonical name of a type or package.
> - A single-static-import declaration ([§7.5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.3)) imports all accessible `static` **members** with a given name from a type, by giving its canonical name.
> - A static-import-on-demand declaration ([§7.5.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.4)) imports all accessible `static` **members** of a named type as needed, by mentioning the canonical name of a type.

As you can see, it's either a **single** named type, or **all accessible** types. No syntax for a *list* of types.

---

*Side note:* I almost never look at the `import` statements of my code. I let Eclipse manage that for me *(Source > Organize Imports... (Ctrl+Shift+O))*, so I don't really care about having many single-type import statements. The section with the imports is collapsed anyway, so I don't even have to scroll past them. Oh the **joy of using a good IDE**.

Answer (score 1):

No. Java doesn't have a construct to import a set of select classes using one statement. You either import all types from the package, or you import them one by one.

Using `*` lets you import all classes from the same package (not to import sub-packages, as you mentioned):

```
import package.*; //Both Class1 and Class2 are imported
import static package.Class1.* //All static members of Class1 are imported
```

The first form `import package.*` is usually discouraged because of the increased potential for name clashes (same class names from different packages). This is probably where `import package.{Class1,Class2}` would have helped, but there's no such construct in Java.

Comment: @Andreas Typo. Fixed... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In java, only supported ways to import multiple classes are as follows :

**A - import individual classes**

```
import package.Class1;
import package.Class2;
```

**B - import all classes in a package or subpackage**

```
import package.*;
import package.subpackage.*;
```

Refer Oracle doc for more information : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html